# Clicking on element with seleniumbase

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors, screen-scraping, seleniumbase

I'm trying to click in a element with `seleniumbase` but its not happening as expected
I tried following method but its not working for some reason:

```
<code>
driver.click('div[class="ovm-OverviewMediaButton me-MediaButtonLoader me-MediaButtonLoader_MLVideo"]')
Received the exception:
seleniumbase.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 
 Element {div[class="ovm-OverviewMediaButton me-MediaButtonLoader me-MediaButtonLoader_MLVideo"]} was not present after 7 seconds! <code>
Trying with only the first class name:
<code> driver.click('div[class="ovm-OverviewMediaButton"]')
seleniumbase.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 
 Element {div[class="ovm-OverviewMediaButton"]} was not present after 7 seconds! <code>
```

The element which im trying to click:

```
<code>
<div class="ovm-OverviewMediaButton me-MediaButtonLoader me-MediaButtonLoader_MLVideo "></div> <code>
```

Comment: There is a space in the end of `@class`, so try exact string: `driver.click('div[class="ovm-OverviewMediaButton me-MediaButtonLoader me-MediaButtonLoader_MLVideo "]')`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a valid selector for that element: `div.ovm-OverviewMediaButton`.

To click it with the seleniumbase `driver`, use:

```py
driver.click("div.ovm-OverviewMediaButton")
```

Comment: Why do you think that OP uses **invalid** selector?

Comment: Whenever you have a long list of classnames, it's more reliable (and cleaner) to pick one and use `.class` notation. A website can easily add/remove a classname, breaking your selector.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but when you said that your selector **is valid** you hinted that OP uses **invalid** selector which is not true and that can mislead OP. It's better to suggest your answer as **more reliable** and I guess it will work, but it won't really allow OP to understand the root cause of the problem.